# Loop trough all folders recursively end execute make command when Makefile present

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I really suck in bash scripting, so i'm hoping on your help guys. I need a script which will loop trough all folders, sub folders, sub sub folders, etc. inside folder /home/work and if there is present file Makefile then it should execute command make install

Folder structure is random, for example /home/work

```
 - Dir 1
 - - Dir 1.1
 - - Dir 1.2
 - - - Makefile
 - Dir 2
 - - Makefile
 - Dir 3
 - - Dir 3.1
 - - Dir 3.2
 - - - Dir 3.2.1
 - - - Makefile
 - - MakeFile
```

This is what i have so far

```
for f in /home/work/*;
  do
     [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f && make install
  done;
```

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide.

Comment: you can have a one liner using the find command and its exec parameter.   $ find /home/work -name Makefile -exec 'cd  basename {}; make; cd $OLDPWD'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find /home/work -type f -name Makefile -execdir make install \;
```

`find` recursively searches `/home/work` for files (`-type f`) named `Makefile` (`-name Makefile`) and runs `make install` in the directory where the file was found (`-execdir make install \;`).

Alternatively, if you're using bash, enable `**` (which is recursive):

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then do:

```
for f in /home/work/**/;
do
     [[ -f $f/Makefile ]] && echo Entering into "$f" && make -C "$f" install
done
```

With a trailing slash after the wildcard, bash will only select directories, so you can eliminate that check. And `make` has an option to change directories before starting: [`-C`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/make.1.html). So, we can avoid the `cd` as well:

```
-C dir, --directory=dir
    Change  to  directory  dir  before  reading the makefiles or doing
    anything else.  If multiple -C  options  are  specified,  each  is
    interpreted  relative  to  the  previous  one:  -C  /  -C  etc  is
    equivalent to -C /etc.  This  is  typically  used  with  recursive
    invocations of make.
```